# TItle and Link Not Getting printed for Google Search

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape Title,Description and URL from Google Search Page using beautifulsoup and python.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup    

query = input("Enter your value: ")
print("Search Term:" + query)     # query = 'Python'

links = [] # Initiate empty list to capture final results
titles = []
descriptions = []
# Specify number of pages on google search, each page contains 10 #links
n_pages = 6 
for page in range(1, n_pages):
    url = "http://www.google.com/search?q=" + query + "&start=" + str((page - 1) * 10)
    
    print("Link : " + url)
    driver.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    
    try:
        search = soup.find_all('div', class_ = "yuRUbf")
        for link in search:
            links.append(link.a['href'])

        description = soup.find_all('div', class_ = "VwiC3b yXK7lf MUxGbd yDYNvb lyLwlc lEBKkf")
        for d in description:
            description_text.append(d.span.text)

        title = soup.find_all('div', class_ = "yuRUbf")
        for t in title:
            titles.append(t.h3.text)
    
    
    # Next loop if one element is not present
    except:
        continue

    
print(links)
print(len(links))


print(description_text)
print(len(description_text))


print(titles)
print(len(titles))
```

The description is getting stored in a list however the links and title list is empty. I inspected the elements and I am using correct class but still unable to get the data.
Can someone help me figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Please write a Minimal Reproducible Example, we can't know which page you're trying to parse, how you use Beautifulsoup etc.

Comment: You can't do that using bs4 only  because  google search depends  on lots of  dynamic elements.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I find working with many lists irritating and cumbersome, when content can be stored directly and structured but anyway you can get information without selecting the dynamic classes in a more generic way:

```
for r in soup.select('#search a h3'):
            data.append({
                'title':r.text,
                'url':r.parent['href'],
                'desc':r.parent.parent.nextSibling.span.text if r.parent.parent.nextSibling.span else 'no desc'
             })
```

#### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

query = input("Enter your value: ")
print("Search Term:" + query)     # query = 'Python'

data = []
n_pages = 6 
for page in range(1, n_pages):
    
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36'}
    url = f'http://www.google.com/search?q={query}&start={str((page - 1) * 10)}'

    r = requests.get(url, headers= headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

    for r in soup.select('#search a h3'):
        data.append({
            'title':r.text,
            'url':r.parent['href'],
            'desc':r.parent.parent.nextSibling.span.text if r.parent.parent.nextSibling.span else 'no desc'
         })
data
```

#### Output

```
[{'title': 'Welcome to Python.org',
  'url': 'https://www.python.org/',
  'desc': 'The official home of the Python Programming Language.'},
 {'title': 'Python (Programmiersprache) - Wikipedia',
  'url': 'https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(Programmiersprache)',
  'desc': 'Python ([ˈpʰaɪθn̩], [ ˈpʰaɪθɑn], auf Deutsch auch [ ˈpʰyːtɔn]) ist eine universelle, üblicherweise interpretierte, höhere Programmiersprache.'},
 {'title': 'Pythons - Wikipedia',
  'url': 'https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythons',
  'desc': 'Die Pythons (Pythonidae; altgr. Πύθων Pythōn; Einzahl der, allgemeinsprachlich auch die Python) sind eine Familie von Schlangen aus der Überfamilie der\xa0...'},
 {'title': 'Das Python-Tutorial — Das Python3.3-Tutorial auf Deutsch',
  'url': 'https://py-tutorial-de.readthedocs.io/',
  'desc': 'Python ist eine einfach zu lernende, aber mächtige Programmiersprache mit effizienten abstrakten Datenstrukturen und einem einfachen, aber effektiven Ansatz\xa0...'},...]
```